# Understand g++ linker when A references B and B ref C, but C is not found

Tags: linker, ld

I have a C++ program **P** that links to a dynamic library **D**, which in turns links to another dynamic library **Z**.

**P** is **not** directly calling any method/var/class of the library **Z**.

I compiled **D** from source code and everything went well.

When I try to compile **P** the linker complains about not finding methods in **Z**. I fixed this linking to **Z** as well.

I would expect however, that since **P** does not directly call any method from **Z**, the linker would be "happy" just with **D**

My questions are:

- What are the possible causes of this specific situation i.e. being forced to link to **Z** as well?
- Is my solution a hack or a good solution?

Please note that my intention to have a deeper understanding about the functioning of the ld linker.

**EDIT**: This question is within the context of Linux. The dynamic libraries refered here are shared objects.

Comment: This behavior is as expected, and your solution is the generally accepted method of dealing with this.

Comment: Thanks, but why does this happens? Is not enough with only D? I mean P uses methods in D. D is already compiled. Finding Z should be a matter in execution time, not in linking time. It obviously seems I'm wrong with that, but I would like to understand why.

Comment: what sort of "dynamic library"?  (e.g. Windows DLLs behave differently to Linux shared objects)

Comment: Linux shared objects. I will edit my question to reflect this. Thanks

Comment: What ha this to do with C++?